# Realm database - NullPointer when trying to get maximum id

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, realm

I am using Realm database on Android, and wrote a function to get Id for autoincrement, since it's not implemented by default afaik. When trying to list objects and count them I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.Map.get(java.lang.Object)
 at io.realm.RealmQuery.maximumInt(RealmQuery.java:1097)                                                           
 at mypackage.api.RealmAPI.id(RealmAPI.java:78)' on a null object reference
```

Code:

```
public class RealmAPI {

private static Context context;
private static RealmConfiguration realmConfig;
private static RealmAPI instance;

public RealmAPI(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                 .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
}

public static RealmAPI getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new RealmAPI(context);
    return instance;
}
  public int id(Class<? extends RealmObject> aClass) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(realmConfig);
    Log.d("realm", realm.where(aClass).count()+"");

     // exception below
      return realm.where(aClass).count() == 0 ?  0 : 
              (int) realm.where(aClass).maximumInt("id") + 1;
}
}
```

Comment: Does `aClass` have a field named `id`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes, it does. I managed to find a workaround by using `realm.where(aClass).findAll().max("id").intValue() + 1`. Still don't know why  the previous version didn't work, i took it from here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/469#issuecomment-91157087

Comment: Wow I feel stupid that I didn't notice, what you get from `max` is a `Number` and you have to call `intValue()` to get an `int` since 0.86.0... I thought `maximumInt()` was removed at that time, not sure how you were still using it